# Handling user account usage with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, user-accounts

I'm building an application that'll let users have a basic account with the ability to buy more usage for their account. For example, a user can only have 50mb of data after which they can buy more among other things...

The issue I'm wondering about is how to store this information in a table and how to manage their current usage and their current limits. Would it be best to store this information into a single table such as:

```
Usage
-------------------
id
user_id
mb_used
mb_limit
xx_used
xx_limit
etc
```

Then would I just update the limit as they order more megabytes etc? I've thought about predetermined packages, but for this application it would not be acceptable.

Let me know if you need more information to give better guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have xx_used and xx_limit, are these for othe "other things..."?

Comment: @Jason, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For megabytes, a flat table will be fine. Explain more about your table and I could help you further.

For now I'll just list some considerations when using a single table architecture.

Versioning and history is difficult with one table. What happens if a person wants to look at a history of how many megs that they have purchased?

access speeds to the table - depending on how your application works - are there more inserts then selects? are the mb fields accessed more often than the "xx" fields? splitting the table up can increase the speed

You could also use a flat file table and still perform version history.

I guess it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Payment records would be saved in another table for history purposes, but I don't think calculating the limits using that table would be a good idea, unless you're talking about something else. Even then I would still need a usage table for storing their current usages correct? I'm only tracking a max of 5 different usage stats.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a report table - like snapshot after each or daily operation on the account:

Usage:

- id
- user_id
- mb_used
- mb_limit
- timestamp

Comment: I'll need the most recent data of the user's stats for them to preform actions on their account, if it is below the limit.

Comment: You are asking for opinion about small peace of cake but hide rest of it... Can you present much bigger scheme of data flow in order to undestand proccess ?

Comment: What I've said in the original post and comments is the slice of cake I can provide. I'm not at disclosure to discuss specifics as this is my client's project. In a general statement, I just want to know the best practice for creating a table or tables for a user's usages and their limits.

Comment: then perhaps your client should hire someone that knows how to do the job with out asking a bunch of strangers on the internet

Comment: @Dagon, or I'm curious how other people or projects have solved this issue? I'm not a DBA nor do I expect a DBA to give me the "correct and best" table scheme. Just looking for guidance. Doesn't look like SO is your type of site then if you don't want to help out strangers, no? Also, by being a flexible question, the help that I would receive would benefit those in same situations for a client or self project. Notice Jason's answer is as vague as my question, giving me enough information to test both ideas to come to the conclusion that, understanding my client needs, would I think be "best".

Comment: @Dagon, Bensiu's answer only restates what I have already posted. Had he explained why it would or wouldn't work or what situations it's better for, like reporting and not real time, then I would give it more thought. Besides, I only commented back to him saying it would be for the most recent data, which I would expect either an IDK, a comment back explaining more details, or asking for more general information, as writing the whole cake in my original post would make too many variables that would make the question itself too specific and only benefit myself, not the rest of SO community.